# Could we make [grammaticality] a synonym of [grammar]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-cleaning

I know we [don't really like the grammar tag](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2699/is-this-tag-useful-episode-1-the-big-boss-grammar) around here. The tag wiki says:

> This tag is for grammar questions, but only if you're not certain what other tag to use. If possible, tag as tense, verb, articles, prepositions, or some other more specific tag or tags instead.

Now I think it's a fantastic idea to use more specific tags rather than grammar, but I don't think that [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) is much better, just slightly rarer.

The tag [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) is about:

> Grammaticality refers to whether something obeys the rules of English grammar.

This seems like a great candidate for synonymizing. Tagging a question with [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) provides no new information.

I would have proposed a synonym myself, but I have a measly [0 points](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:15406+[grammaticality]) in this particular tag, so I can't really do anything about it.

Comment: I think there is a slight difference though. "Is this grammatical?" is grammaticality. Questions explicitly about the grammatical rules of English (which we don't get many that can't be tagged with other tags) are grammar. I also think there's some value to leaving grammar as is because to me it means "please help me tag my question".

Comment: @Colleen there *is* a difference. The question is whether that difference is being taken into account. From what I've seen, it isn't, but I'm not a good judge, since I hold a grudge against these tags. :)

Comment: @IͶΔ I really dislike [tag:grammar] because it does get abused, but it's not the tag's fault! We should have some empathy and help it become all that it was meant to be not synonymize it out of existence. :) I'm already seeing some learners choose grammaticality over grammar, so I'm hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

In a site for a language learners, it is probable users are using [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) when asking about the grammaticality of a phrase; if they were interested in the syntax of a phrase, they would use [syntax](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax), which is another tag we have. Otherwise, the tag seems a little too broad, IMO.

I would rather make it a synonym of [grammaticality](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), after editing those questions that could use another tag.